# What is the rear hub of a Giant ATX 2 2019/2020?

Tags: wheels

My question is about the Giant ATX 2 2019/20 model. Is the hub a freehub for a cassette or a hub for a freewheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freewheel have almost completely been superseded by freehubs and cassettes, however the Giant ATX is an inexpensive bike with a Tourney level groupset, so It could conceivably have a freewheel.

It's simple to look up the bike's specs and find out. [This is the ATX 2 page at the giant site](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/atx-2). The site says it has a Shimano MF-TZ500 14x34 'cassette'. The 14 tooth small sprocket gives us a clue that this is a freewheel.

Looking at the [Shimano page for the MF-TZ500](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/MF-TZ500-7.html) we see that it is indeed a 7 speed freewheel.